# parse table columns into array

Tags: java, arrays, parsing

I am iterating over the table and I want to parse column 1 and column 2 into 2 separate arrays. I am not sure how to do this. Here is the code I have written so far:

```
while (line !="table_end"){
     for (line = bufferedReader.readLine(); line != null; line = bufferedReader.readLine()){
                         String[] rowData = line.split("\t");

                         for (int i = 0; i < rowData.length; i++) {
                             String id = rowData[0];// ids
                             System.out.println(id);
                             String nid = rowData[1];// names
                             System.out.println(nid);
                             //create arrays out of this
```

The loop extracts the first (rowData[0]) and second row data (rowData[1]) from the table, and i want to store all rowData[0] entries in one array, and rowData[1] entries in another array.

Besides that, i get an error when the loop ends, because it includes the line "table_end".

The table looks like this:

```
data0  data1 number number number etc
data0  data1 number number number etc
data0  data1 number number number etc
 this goes on for about 1000 rows
table_end
```

I am a beginner in Java and I need advise on how to store each rowData[0] and [1] in separate arrays and how to not read the last line, "table_end".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well it can be managed in the while with a condition in this case

```
while (line !="table_end"){      
       for (line = bufferedReader.readLine(); line != null; 
                    line = bufferedReader.readLine()) { 
           if ( !line.equals("table_end"){
               //Do other things here
           }
    }
  }
```

I assumed you just don't need "table_end" to be included hop it helps
and for storing the rowData[0] in 1 array and rowData[0] in another you have 2 options either 
if the length is specific have 2 loops inside the for and then add these elements to 2 other arrays or if the length is not specific adds them to ArrayList and later on convert ArrayList to array of String

```
 ArrayList<String> firstArray = new ArrayList<String>(); 
 ArrayList<Strign> secondArray = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and inside the loop you'll have

```
       firstArray.add(rowdata[0);
       secondArray.add(rowdata[1);
```

Comment: thanks, figured out how to do this with ArrayList, but still confused about how to make it not read the last line.

Comment: maybe I'm confused about what you need your code does but according to my understanding if you change this line for (line = bufferedReader.readLine(); line != null;  line = bufferedReader.readLine()) with for (line = bufferedReader.readLine(); line != null && !(line.equals("table_end"));  line = bufferedReader.readLine()) it should do what you need let me know if it helps

Answer (score 0):

As you probably do not know how many `bufferedReader` will yield you should put your `id`s and you `nid`s into `ArrayList<String>` objects (e.g. `ids` and `nids`) and convert those to arrays in the end.